# Expand/Collapse sidebar with the same button with Ember

Tags: jquery, css, ember.js

I'm trying to implement simple behavior to learn Ember and I'm hitting a wall with the sidebar implementation.

This is an expandable/collapsable sidebar with icons. When icon is clicked, it is highlighted and the corresponding content is displayed on the expanded sidebar pane. When clicking again on the same icon, the sidebar collapse and the application returns to the corresponding index route.

I got quite close to this defined behavior but I always miss a little thing.

```
<div id="sidebar" {{bind-attr class='selectedTab::collapsed'}}>
<div id="sidebar-items">
    {{#each}}
        {{#link-to target tagName="li"}}
            <a {{bind-attr href=view.href}}>{{fa-icon icon}}</a>
        {{/link-to}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
<div id="sidebar-pane">
    {{outlet}}
</div>
</div>
```

In this implementation, I can not collapse the sidebar because if I click again on the same icon, Ember does not attempt the route again so I can't reach the code where I'm testing the requested route against the current one, and where I transition to index route if equals. I tried with the willTransition hook with no success.

```
<div id="sidebar" {{bind-attr class='selectedTab::collapsed'}}>
<div id="sidebar-items">
    {{#each}}
        <li>
            <a {{action 'selectTab' target}}>
                {{fa-icon icon}}
            </a>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</div>
<div id="sidebar-pane">
    {{outlet}}
</div>
</div>
```

This is the closer I got to what I need.
In this one, I can make all the process in the selectTab function and redirect to the correct route, or index if I detect this is the same route as the current one. The sidebar expand and collapse, the content pane is updated accordingly with the route. But, I didn't find how to bind the active class on the selected `<li>` AND remove the active class on all siblings.

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you maybe post a pic of the UI you're aiming for? It sounds kind of like a tabs widget, and if so you'll probably want to use components here.

Comment: This is very similar (almost identical) to the leaflet-sidebar-v2 library, but with dynamic content managed with Ember. I thought about component but the sidebar is meant to be an interface to interact with the map and with the whole application. Components seem to be designed as self-contained logic. I probably missed something there.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what's going on with your `{{#each}}`. Is that each model, controller, something else?

In any case, whatever this is (lets say a `Tab` model), you just want to know if a `Tab` `isSelected` or not. Then, you can bind the class to `isSelected` while you're iterating over `each`.

If the controller is handling `selectTab`, it should just be able to do something like this:

```
selectTab: function(tab) {
  this.get('tabs').setEach('isSelected', false);
  tab.set('isSelected', true);
}
```

Then you can do `<li {{bind-attr class='isSelected:active'}}>`.